# Wanting to declare preBuild event command to change MSBuild to earlier version

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-2000, dbml

So my issue is that I have a project with a DBML file that I am trying to Build/connect to a SQL 2000 database. We are currently using VS 2013 for the rest of our solution. My question is, is there a way to specify a Pre-build event to use VS 2008 MSBuild for the specific project that needs to use it? If so what would that command line look like? I know the other work around I've seen is just build it in 2008 and manually move the DBML file over to the 2013 solution and as long as the OLE data adapter is installed/set it will work, but it seems really bad practice to manually move it around instead of just making it part of the build in the same solution....

Comment: given the pre/post-build events run in a cmd.exe instance, it's probably a matter of setting the correct environment variables and/or calling said msbuild version directly by specifying the full path to it